# JPA - Cascade persist on one to one relationship

Tags: java, jpa, primary-key, cascade, one-to-one

I have a bidirectional one to one relationship and I want the id of one of the entities be the other's Id as well.

my code is something like this:

```
@Entity
public class UserProfile extends AbstractEntity{
     @OneToOne(mappedBy="user",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
     private UserPreferences preferences;

     //...
}
```

the other entity:

```
@Entity
public class UserPreferences implements Serializable{
  @Id
  @Column(name="USER_ID")
  private String userId;  // I want USER_ID act as both primary key and foreign key

  @OneToOne
  @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="USER_ID")
  UserProfile user;

  // ...
}
```

but when I persist a UserProfile like this:

```
UserPreferences pref = new UserPereferences();
pref.setUser(user);
user.setPreferences(pref);
em.persist(user);
```

it gives me an error which says that UserPreferences' Id cannot be null
it seems that jpa does not understand that it should use the UserProfile Id as UserPreferences Id.

error:

```
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'USER_ID' cannot be null
Error Code: 1048
Call: INSERT INTO USERPREFERENCES (USER_ID) VALUES (?)
```

is there something wrong in my code? can jpa solve this? or I should persist them separately?

thanks in advance

Comment: are you using hibernate? Are you generating the DDL with it?

Comment: I'm using eclipselink, and yes I was generating ddl, I removed the userId and added Id annotation to user and it worked ( as hide suggested )
I haven't tried MapsId as owen said, but I believe that works too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont do this

```
@Id
@Column(name="USER_ID")
private String userId;  // I want USER_ID act as both primary key and foreign key

@OneToOne
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="USER_ID")
UserProfile user;
```

Because you are using a reference two times, just need use one

```
@OneToOne
@Id
@Column(name="USER_ID")
UserProfile user;
```

Like this for example

Answer (score 2):

Use `@MapsId` instead of `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn`

```
@Entity
public class UserPreferences implements Serializable{
  @Id
  @Column(name="USER_ID")
  private String userId;  // I want USER_ID act as both primary key and foreign key

  @MapsId
  @OneToOne
  //@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="USER_ID")
  UserProfile user;

  // ...
}
```

This will create the foreign key definition during DDL generation.

```
CREATE TABLE USERPREFERENCE (USER_ID VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (USER_ID))
CREATE TABLE USERPROFILE (ID VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (ID))
ALTER TABLE SESSION ADD CONSTRAINT FK_SESSION_USER_ID FOREIGN KEY (USER_ID) REFERENCES USER (ID)
ALTER TABLE USERPREFERENCE ADD CONSTRAINT FK_USERPREFERENCE_USER_ID FOREIGN KEY (USER_ID) REFERENCES USERPROFILE (ID)
```

Answer (score 1):

The annotation itself is not enough to actually cascade operations on related tables. You should also find a "ON XXX CASCADE" on the FK UserPreferences -> UserProfile.

If you're using JPA to create DDL, you should read it on the UserPreferences Table. If DB is already created, you should drop the constraint and then add the CASCADE manually, with something like this:

```
 alter table UserPreferences  drop constraint OldConstraintName;
 alter table UserPreferences  add constraint FK_ABABA foreign key (USERID) references UserProfile(USERID) on delete/update/etc.. cascade
```